# MVC displaying appropriate Value instead of Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Assume we have one table:

```
Person[ID,NAME,GENDER]
id = 1, name = Mozart, gender = 1
id = 2, name = Sissy, gender = 2
...
```

And I have a *KeyValuePair* collection with

```
key = 1, value = MALE
key = 2, value = FEMALE
...
```

How can I display on MVC View instead of gender its value ?

```
like this:
---------
Persons
1 | Mozart | MALE
2 | Sissy | FEMALE
---------
```

Controller and the View are as simple as it is possible:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> genders = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    public ActionResult Index() {
        genders.Add(1, "male");
        genders.Add(2, "female");

        return View( dbContext.Persons.ToList() );
    }
}

@model IEnumerable<Models.Person>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit", new { id = item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "UserDelete", new { id = item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can we see your view too?

Comment: View, ViewModel, and Controller code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a view model that contains exactly the properties that you need.

View Model

```
public class PersonViewModel{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when you populate this view model, you can do the lookup directly in your code and pass the appropriate information

```
var genderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
genderDictionary.Add(1, "Male");
genderDictionary.Add(2, "Female");
var people = db.Persons.ToList().Select(x=>new PersonViewModel{
     Id = x.Id, 
     Name = x.Name,
     Gender = genderDictionary[x.Gender]
});
return people;
```

Lastly, your view's model should be updated to the following

```
@Model IEnumerable<Namespace.PersonViewModel>
```

Alternatively, you could pass your dictionary to your view in the viewdata object.  Then, use that when you are doing your loop and perform the lookup there.  However, using strongly-typed views (as above) is the better practice to get into when doing .NET MVC development.  This is here more for information than a "how you should do it".

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult People(){

   var model = db.Persons.ToList();
   ViewData["genderDictionary"] = yourKeyValuePair;
   return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@{
  var genderDictionary = (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewData["genderDictionary"];
  foreach(var person in Model){
     <tr>
        <td>@person.Name</td>
        <td>@genderDictionary[person.Gender]</td>
     </tr>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been created the separated ViewModel, and it helped. Respect!