# MVC in ASP.NET - Displaying a value instead of Id using IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This question sort of has an answer on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042070/mvc-displaying-appropriate-value-instead-of-key), but it's over 5 years old and I'm not sure it's the best or only way, particularly because I already have a Dictionary-type object - a list of

I have a ViewModel:

```
public class SummaryList
{
    public List<Summary> Summaries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Managers { get; set; }

    public SummaryList()
    {
        Managers = new DAL.GetManagersAsSelectListItem();
    }
}
```

The `Summary` Model looks something like this:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
... OtherProperties ...
public int ManagerId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Managers { get; set; }
```

On a page where the user can edit this ViewModel, which shows the entire `List` of `Summary` objects, I can do this:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.SummaryList

@using (Html.BeginForm("SummaryListSave", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.Summaries.Count > 0)
        {
          <table>
            <thead>...</thead>

            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Summaries.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Summaries[i].WhateverProperty)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Summaries[i].ManagerId, Model.Managers)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 }
             </tbody>

           </table>
         }
     }
 }
```

i.e. I can show a DropDownList for each row which takes the `ManagerId` and because I provide the IEnumerable `Managers` it does my two-way binding for ddl options and for saving the edits.

I want to do the same as this but only DISPLAY the value, so not using a DropDownList, instead of showing `ManagerId` I want the respective value from the `SelectListItem`

Is there no mechanism in the `Html` helpers to do this, using my already existing/populated SelectListItem? I tried `DisplayTextFor` and a few others but no success yet.

If none exist, what would be the easiest way to implement something using the Enumerable

**My first idea is to wrap the parameter on the line** `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OutbreakSummaries[i].WeeklyMeetingLeadId)`, which will give the Id, in a function that gets the value from `Model.Managers` but I don't know where to start with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood, but did you try using (SelectList) in your View, and also indicating the Value and Text properties when creating the SelectList in controller?
like this:

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Summaries[i].ManagerId, (SelectList) Model.Managers)
```

**Controller:**

```
Model.Managers = new SelectList(new DAL.GetManagersAsSelectListItem(), "ManagerID", "Description");
```

Replace *Description* wih the real property name inside Manager VM (for Text)
When this is configured like this, the DropDownList should show the Text and not the Value (id).

Comment: Thanks! This helps my progress on the `edit` view, but I also want to be able to have the `Text` as a normal `Display` on the plain `details` view (so showing the text but not inside a dropDownList)

Comment: Don't you have a Manager object property inside your Summary ViewModel? If you have it, on every loop in the View you can show any of its properties:
@Html.DosplayFor(m => m.Summaries[i].Manager.Id)
@Html.DosplayFor(m => m.Summaries[i].Manager.Description)

In the Detail Function in the controller, you would add the corresponding Manager to each Summary.

Comment: No I hadn't created a separate class ViewModel for the Manager object, I just had the `Id` and a `List<SelectListItem>` on the main `Summaries` class. I guess this is where I've been going wrong. It worked for a purpose but has made it difficult to implement other things.